# How to use Stack<String> properly

Tags: java, string, parameters, stack

I'm not familiar with the usage of Stack. In the code below, I was suggested to use **`Stack<String>`** as one of my parameters - tracing through the segment of code, I can't say that I know for sure how to use it/what it's for. I have not test it yet. Some suggestions?

Incomplete Method:

```
public void print(String phrase, int max) {
    if (phrase == null || max < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

}// End of print helper method
```

Public Method:

```
public void print(String phrase) {
    Stack<String> stack = new Stack<>();
    LetterCounter letter = new LetterCounter(phrase);
    print((Set<String>) printList, letter, stack);
} // End of print method
```

Private helper method:

```
 private void print(Set<String> s, LetterCounter letter, Stack<String> chosen) {
    if (letter.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println(chosen);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Letter: " + letter);
        for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
            String choice = s.toArray()[i].toString();
            if (letter.contains(choice)) {
                chosen.push(choice);
                letter.subtract(choice);
                s.remove(choice);
                System.out.println("Chosen: " + chosen);
                System.out.println("Letter: " + letter);
            }
        }
    }
}// End of (helper) print method
```

Some background info:

Class: [link](http://pastebin.com/KQSepSJH)

Client Class: [link](http://pastebin.com/C76J7UcW)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Eran Ultimately, I'm trying to print out lists of anagrams derived from a given phrase. The number of anagrams per lists is within the range of int max. The total number of lists relies on how many anagrams can be found from a dictionary.txt file from the given phrase.